# Best practice for creating a youtube gallery of embedded videos?

Tags: html, youtube

I'm curious to what the best practice is in regards to embedding youtube videos on a site? Ideally I will want to auto-play a default video with it muted while having other videos available as thumbnails.

Any recommended plugins? Should I use an iframe or an object?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very broad: it's hard to know how to help you. If you're using WordPress, for instance, you'll have some plugins to help you do this, but otherwise it depends on whether you intend to dynamically generate the videos or manually create a page with the main video and thumbnails chosen by you in advance.

If you intend to program your page, you'll want to use the [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/) (version 3 preferably, which uses JSON to keep payload sizes down).

If you're manually laying the page out, look at the watch page for a YouTube video, and you can get the embed code there. Click 'Share -> Embed' and then you'll see an `iframe` tag from which you can fiddle with to alter the size parameters to suit your needs.

One thing to note though: if you make a video **autoplay** on a page, as far as I know you forfeit the opportunity to have the viewcount increase for that video. So if you want to promote one of your own and intend the viewcount to go up each time, you have to allow users to start the video.

Comment: So iframe if I'm just manually laying out one video? If I want to have a thumbnail system, where each thumbnail could be clicked and bring up a new video - I would then use the YouTube Data API?

Comment: And could you provide a link to an example if you have one handy.

Comment: No, the question isn't between using an iframe or not, it's whether you are programmatically doing all this or not. You could still do thumbnails (depending on what size you can go to with the embedding options from YouTube) manually.